# How do I create a new HttpSession in a RESTful webapp?

Tags: java, tomcat, rest, restful-authentication

I have a need to create a HttpSession (via cookie) whenever a client invokes a particular UI.

Assumptions:

- Let's assuming that I'm not going to worry about any deep oAuth-like authentication dance. JESSIONSID cookie impersonation is not an issue for now.
- The server is tomcat, thus a JSESSIONID cookie is sent down to the client if a new session is created.

Design issues:

1. I'm grappling with how to design the URI. What is actually the REST resource ? I already have **/users** and **/users/{someuserid}**. I wanted to use **/auth/login** but in one previous SO question, one [cited article](http://prescod.net/rest/mistakes/) says that we should not have verbs in the url. I've noticed that even [Google makes the same mistake](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/gdata/articles/oauth.html) by having **https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken**. So in your opinion, are **/auth/login/johndoe** (login) and **/auth/logout/johndoe** (logout) good options ?

UPDATE:

I've changed my design. I'm now thinking of using the URIs **/session/johndoe** (*PUT* for login, *DELETE* for logout). It should still be within the limits of the REST ethos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in the midst of creating a REST endpoint that recognizes sessions. I've standardized on:

- POST /sessions => returns Location: http://server/api/sessions/1qazwsxcvdf
- DELETE /sessions/1qazwsxcvdf => invalidates session

It is working well.

Answer (score 4):

Aren't sessions irrelevant in REST Style Architecture?

http://www.prescod.net/rest/mistakes/

Comment: In my case, I really need to have a session. Because each session establishment consumes a "considerable" resource in my backend.

Comment: If you really "need" this session then I suggest you stop trying to make your application RESTful.  You will be swimming upstream all the way.  Removing "application state" from the server is one of the core constraints of REST.

Comment: I have no other choice. The webapp is in a servlet container.